# What is the most recommeded Gif creation plugin for sketch

Tags: animation, sketch-app, gif

I am new to sketch and I am looking to make animated gif's like I do in photoshop, Is there a plugin that can do this probably with a timeline too?

Comment: What have you looked into thus far?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to have a timeline in Sketch for creating GIF's but please correct me if I'm wrong.

There is a good plugin, which allows you to view images in a art board and in key frames and piece them together in order to create a GIF, so this is probably the sort of plugin you are looking for.

It is known as **Generate GIF** and I have posted the download link below.

https://github.com/nathco/Generate-GIF

I'm sure there is plenty of videos on YouTube demostrating the use of this plugin.

Please let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

There's none with a timeline that I know of at the moment. Besides generate gif mentioned by miotik (which works well with the [Frame Sequencer Plugin](https://github.com/dawidw/frame-sequencer)), there's [AnimateMate](http://animatemate.com/), which does automatic tweening and easing.

In my experience none of these are enough for more complex animations where you have to move several objects, but will do fine for more simple ones. I ended using Fireworks for more intricate work.